# SPARQL request using python works but leads to JSONDecodeError once the requested timeframe is expanded

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, sparql, wikidata

I am facing a problem while trying to request data from wikidata in python and would highly appreciate any help.

While generally working (illustrated by CODE SNIPPET 1), running the code leads to a JSONDecodeError error when the query is slightly modified so that a longer period is covered (shown by CODE SNIPPET 2)...

CODE SNIPPET 1:

```
query = """
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?dob ?place_of_birth ?place_of_birthLabel ?date_of_death ?place_of_death ?place_of_deathLabel ?political_party ?political_partyLabel ?sex_or_gender ?sex_or_genderLabel ?Wikimedia_import_URL ?occupation ?occupationLabel ?work_location ?work_locationLabel ?educated_at ?educated_atLabel ?imported_from_Wikimedia_project ?imported_from_Wikimedia_projectLabel ?source_website_for_the_property ?stated_in ?stated_inLabel ?religion ?religionLabel ?VIAF_ID ?ISNI ?Deutsche_Biographie_ID ?DBS_ID ?place_of_detention ?place_of_detentionLabel ?country_of_citizenship ?country_of_citizenshipLabel ?member_of_military_unit ?member_of_military_unitLabel ?conflict ?conflictLabel ?military_rank ?military_rankLabel ?military_branch ?military_branchLabel ?participant_in ?participant_inLabel ?award_received ?award_receivedLabel ?described_by_source ?described_by_sourceLabel ?academic_degree ?academic_degreeLabel ?field_of_work ?field_of_workLabel ?noble_title ?noble_titleLabel WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
    wdt:P569 ?dob.
  FILTER(("1870-01-02"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dob) && (?dob <= "1870-01-04"^^xsd:dateTime))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P19 ?place_of_birth. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P570 ?date_of_death. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P20 ?place_of_death. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P102 ?political_party. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P21 ?sex_or_gender. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P4656 ?Wikimedia_import_URL. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P937 ?work_location. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P69 ?educated_at. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P143 ?imported_from_Wikimedia_project. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P1896 ?source_website_for_the_property. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P248 ?stated_in. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P140 ?religion. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P214 ?VIAF_ID. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P213 ?ISNI. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P7902 ?Deutsche_Biographie_ID. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P4007 ?DBS_ID. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P5019 ?occupation. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P2632 ?place_of_detention. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P27 ?country_of_citizenship. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P7779 ?member_of_military_unit. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P607 ?conflict. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P410 ?military_rank. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P241 ?military_branch. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P1344 ?participant_in. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P166 ?award_received. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P1343 ?described_by_source. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P512 ?academic_degree. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P101 ?field_of_work. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P97 ?noble_title. }
}
"""

import requests

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
r = requests.get(url, params={'format': 'json', 'query': query})

json_format = r.json()
```

The error occurs if this line from CODE SNIPPET 1:

```
FILTER(("1870-01-02"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dob) && (?dob <= "1870-01-04"^^xsd:dateTime))
```

Is replaced by this line (CODE SNIPPET 2):

```
FILTER(("1870-01-02"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?dob) && (?dob <= "1874-01-04"^^xsd:dateTime))
```

The error resulting from the replacement reads out as follows:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 2345752 column 44 (char 64968579)
```

After browsing the internet for help, I added "strict=False" to the line, which is responsible for the decoding (to get rid of problems caused by the inclusion of patterns like '\n' in the retrieved data), resulting in CODE SNIPPET 3:

```
import requests

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
r = requests.get(url, params={'format': 'json', 'query': query})

json_format = r.json(strict=False)
```

However, this triggered another kind of decoding error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2031964 column 9 (char 56246827)
```

So I amended the code once again, trying to avoid the .json() function from the requests library (CODE SNIPPET 4):

```
import requests

url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
r = requests.get(url, params={'format': 'json', 'query': query})

json_str = r.text

import json
json_format = json.loads(json_str, strict=False)
```

resulting in a third kind of decoding error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1521988 column 12 (char 42127071)
```

I also tried to manually replace patterns as '\n' from the variable json_str as defined in the last snippet while having set 'strict=True'. None of my approaches are working, unfortunately.
Okay, that's it for the moment. If anybody has an idea on how to solve the issue, I'd be grateful :)

Cheers,
Marius

Comment: Either the stream is corrupted because of an obviously larger result or the JSON serialization of Blazegraoh has some bug. Did you check the result from commandline?

Comment: I tried your second query from commandline with `curl`, and as expected it 1) lead to a timeout 2) that`s why the JSON is incomplete and 3) contains the error stacktrace which 4) makes it invalid JSON and 5) can't be parsed with a standard JSON parser for good reason. So long story short, your query is too complex for the public shared endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Based on your assessment, I solved the issue by looping over each month and every year with an individual query to reduce the query's complexity. Works pretty well!